# How can I apply changes to source files with Python?

Tags: python, c++, refactoring, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am refactoring C++ code using the Python bindings of the Clang compiler ([cindex](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/bindings/python)). Using that, I analyze the AST and prepare changes. I end up with a list of operations similar to the following:

```
DELETE line 10
INSERT line 5 column 32: <<  "tofu"
REPLACE from line 31 colum 6 to line 33 column 82 with: std::cout << "Thanks SO"
...
```

**My question is how to turn these into actual file changes.**

Doing it directly with python seems tedious: patches need to be applied in the right order and checked for consistency. It looks quite hard and error-prone.

I also can’t find a good library to help (clang does have something called a Rewriter, but it isn't wrapped in Python. I'd really like to avoid C++ for refactoring if possible).

Maybe an idea could be to generate patches and apply them with git, maybe? But even that seems a bit tedious.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you have exhibited is a string of patches; why can't you just apply them in order? [Maybe you are making several overlapping patches to the AST?] Would it be more useful to just modify the AST for each change as you make them, then spit out the revised AST?  Then you can't have an out-of-order patching problem.

Comment: You have to be careful about order as changes can invalidate line numbers. I agree modifying the AST would be the best option, unfortunately cindex does not support it.

Comment: If the tool you have won't do the job well, you can choose another tool.   Check my bio for a tool (DMS) that can parse C++, build and modify C++ ASTs (we did that avoid exactly silly patching problems when composing changes) and then regenerate valid source code.   It isn't in Python, though.  It isn't in C++ either; DMS is an array of DSLs that cooperate to let you specify transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I rolled out my own. The code is almost certainly buggy and not very pretty, but I'm posting it in the hope it might help someone until a better solution is found.

```
class PatchRecord(object):
    """ Record patches, validate them, order them, and apply them """

    def __init__(self):
        # output of readlines for each patched file
        self.lines = {}
        # list of patches for each patched file
        self.patches = {}

    class Patch(object):
        """ Abstract base class for editing operations """

        def __init__(self, filename, start, end):
            self.filename = filename
            self.start = start
            self.end = end

        def __repr__(self):
            return "{op}: {filename} {start}/{end} {what}".format(
                op=self.__class__.__name__.upper(),
                filename=self.filename,
                start=format_place(self.start),
                end=format_place(self.end),
                what=getattr(self, "what", ""))

        def apply(self, lines):
            print "Warning: applying no-op patch"

    class Delete(Patch):

        def __init__(self, filename, extent):
            super(PatchRecord.Delete, self).__init__(
                filename, extent.start, extent.end)
            print "DELETE: {file} {extent}".format(file=self.filename,
                                                   extent=format_extent(extent))

        def apply(self, lines):
            lines[self.start.line - 1:self.end.line] = [
                lines[self.start.line - 1][:self.start.column - 1] +
                lines[self.end.line - 1][self.end.column:]]

    class Insert(Patch):

        def __init__(self, filename, start, what):
            super(PatchRecord.Insert, self).__init__(filename, start, start)
            self.what = what
            print "INSERT {where} {what}".format(what=what, where=format_place(self.start))

        def apply(self, lines):
            line = lines[self.start.line - 1]
            lines[self.start.line - 1] = "%s%s%s" % (
                line[:self.start.column],
                self.what,
                line[self.start.column:])

    class Replace(Patch):

        def __init__(self, filename, extent, what):
            super(PatchRecord.Replace, self).__init__(
                filename, extent.start, extent.end)
            self.what = what
            print "REPLACE: {where} {what}".format(what=what,
                                                   where=format_extent(extent))

        def apply(self, lines):
            lines[self.start.line - 1:self.end.line] = [
                lines[self.start.line - 1][:self.start.column - 1] +
                self.what +
                lines[self.end.line - 1][self.end.column - 1:]]

    # Convenience functions for creating patches
    def delete(self, filename, extent):
        self.patches[filename] = self.patches.get(
            filename, []) + [self.Delete(filename, extent)]

    def insert(self, filename, where, what):
        self.patches[filename] = self.patches.get(
            filename, []) + [self.Insert(filename, where, what)]

    def replace(self, filename, extent, what):
        self.patches[filename] = self.patches.get(
            filename, []) + [self.Replace(filename, extent, what)]

    def _pos_to_tuple(self, position):
        """ Convert a source location to a tuple for use as a sorting key """
        return (position.line, position.column)

    def sort(self, filename):
        """ Sort patches by extent start """
        self.patches[filename].sort(key=lambda p: self._pos_to_tuple(p.start))

    def validate(self, filename):
        """Try to insure patches are consistent"""
        print "Checking patches for %s" % filename
        self.sort(filename)
        previous = self.patches[filename][0]
        for p in self.patches[filename][1:]:
            assert(self._pos_to_tuple(p.start) >
                   self._pos_to_tuple(previous.start))

    def _apply(self, filename):
        self.sort(filename)
        lines = self._getlines(filename)
        for p in reversed(self.patches[filename]):
            print p
            p.apply(lines)

    def _getlines(self, filename):
        """ Get source file lines for editing """
        if not filename in self.lines:
            with open(filename) as f:
                self.lines[filename] = f.readlines()
        return self.lines[filename]

    def apply(self):
        for filename in self.patches:
            self.validate(filename)
            self._apply(filename)
            # with open(filename+".patched","w") as output:
            with open(filename, "w") as output:
                output.write("".join(self._getlines(filename)))
```

Just create a `PatchRecord` object, add changes using the `create`, `replace` and `delete` methods, and apply them with `apply` when you're ready.